# Tags not working in Notification Hub with Swift

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

When I set the tag to nil, it all works great. But formatting the tags doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {

    if Leagues.count > 0 {
        var myLeague: [String] = [String]()
        for eachleague in Leagues {
            myLeague.append(eachleague.LeagueName)
        }


       let categories: NSSet =  NSSet(array: myLeague)

        let hub : SBNotificationHub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString: "Endpoint=<my endpoint>", notificationHubPath: "<myhub>")

        hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: categories as! Set<NSObject>) { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow this example in objective-c: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-send-breaking-news/

Comment: I'm not sure if I've found the solution yet - but I am learning that tags with spaces in them seem to be blocking. Might be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through much trial and error, I was able to create a solution. Hope this helps the next person. First, no spaces in tag names. Second, the signature for the API for Objective-C is different than the one for Swift.

Here's a working Swift example:

```
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {

    if Leagues.count > 0 {
        var myLeague: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
        for eachleague in Leagues {
            myLeague.insert(eachleague.LeagueID, atIndex: 0)
        }

       let tagSet: NSSet = NSSet(array: myLeague)

        let hub : SBNotificationHub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString: gEndPointName, notificationHubPath: gHubName)

        hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: tagSet as! Set<NSObject>) { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your tags are valid:

> A tag can be any string, up to 120 characters, containing alphanumeric
>   and the following non-alphanumeric characters: ‘_’, ‘@’, ‘#’, ‘.’,
>   ‘:’, ‘-’.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx